# Show that there are exactly two Monoids with two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I am new to learning monoid and I know basic ideas about monoid like the operation been defined has to be associative and has unity in a set. But as of this question, I do not even know where to start from. Please, I need a clear explanation or justification of why the statement is true.

Comment: The question should say "two monoids up to isomorphism".

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it is clear that one of the two elements has to be the identity $e$. Now for the other element $a$, it is either a unit or not.

Each of these choices determines the Monoid completely. Can you explicitly give the two?

Comment: @Shaun how do I contradict uniqueness of the identity? Maybe let me note that by unit I do not mean identity

Comment: He means "invertible".

Comment: My bad, sorry :)

Comment: why does one of the two element has to be identity? [Sorry as I said I am very new to this topic, so what you assume I know, I may not...]

Comment: Reread the definition of a monoid, Kay :)

Comment: Got it ! @QiZhu

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Fill out Cayley tables for a set of two elements.

> The two monoids are given by $$\begin{array}{c|cc} \times & x & y \\ \hline x & x & y \\ y & y & x\end{array}$$ and $$\begin{array}{c|cc} \times & a & b \\ \hline a & a & a \\ b & a & b\end{array}.$$